# Why does nn.LayerNorm have two parameters but only one weight?

Tags: pytorch

```
print(nn.LayerNorm(1, elementwise_affine=True).weight)
#Output:
Parameter containing:
tensor([1.], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```

Because elementwise_affine is set to True, there are two tunable parameters. However, when I print the weight of LayerNorm I only get one weight. Why? There should be two elements in this tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are only accessing one of them: `weight`, the other one being the `bias`.

You can access all layer parameters via `parameters`:

```
>>> layer = nn.LayerNorm(1, elementwise_affine=True)
>>> list(layer.parameters())
[Parameter containing:
 tensor([1.], requires_grad=True),
 Parameter containing:
 tensor([0.], requires_grad=True)]
```